# Vim searching: avoid matches within comments

Tags: python, regex, vim

Using vim searching capabilities, is it possible to avoid matching on a comment block/line.

As an example, I would like to match on 'image' in this python code, but only in the code, not in the comment:

```
# Export the image
if export_images and i + j % 1000 == 0:
export_image(img_mask, "images/image{}.png".format(image_id))
image_id += 1
```

Using regular expressions I would do something like this: `/^[^#].*(image).*/gm` 
But it does not seem to work in vim.

Comment: You still can match the text with `/^[^#].*\(image\).*`. But why do you need to capture `image`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't really need to capture it. I just want to find the occurrences of the word. I have tried this `/^[^#].*\(image\).*` but it does not match the text as expected.

Comment: This `^[^#].*image` works for me

Comment: The problem that I have is that it matches at the beginning of the line and therefore the cursor is not on the word 'image'. I was wondering if there was a more intuitive way to just avoid the comments while searching.

Comment: Maybe something like `/^[^#].*\zsimage\ze`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think you should post this as an answer (I mean \zs ... \ze)

Comment: If you're interested in using Vim more efficiently, do checkout [vi.se].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can  use

```
/^[^#].*\zsimage\ze
```

The [`\zs` and `\ze`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#perl-patterns) signalize the start and end of a match respectively.

> - setting the start and end of the match:  `\zs \ze`

Note that this will not match several "image"s on  a line, just the last one.

Also, perhaps, a "negative lookahead" would be better than a negated character class at the beginning:

```
/^#\@!.*\zsimage\ze
  ^^^^
```

The `#\@!` is equal to `(?!#)` in Python.

And **since look-behinds are non-fixed-width in Vim** ([*like `(?<=pattern)` in Perl, but Vim allows non-fixed-width patterns*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@%3C=)), you can match all occurrences of the character sequence *image* with

```
/\(^#\@!.*\)\@<=image
```

And to finally **skip matching *image* on an indented comment line**, you just need to *match* optional (zero or more) whitespace symbol(s) at the beginning of the line:

```
\(^\(\s*#\)\@!.*\)\@<=image
   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This `\(\s*#\)\@!` is equivalent to Python `(?!\s*#)` (match if not followed by zero or more whitespace followed with a `#`).

Comment: Thank you, it is the behavior I wanted. Although I wish there could be a special command to avoid any kind of comment (in any language).

Comment: Thanks, what is the Python equivalent of `\@<=`?

Comment: Same as Perl, `(?<=pattern_here)`, but only a [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) allows an infinite width lookbehind. The `re` module does not allow what I showed with the Vim regex above.

Comment: One last thing is puzzling me, why does it match on an indented commented line? `^` represent the beginning of a string, so why is vim taking tabs into account?

Comment: This is because we have not specified that we may want to *match* the whitespace. You can use `\(^\(\s*#\)\@!.*\)\@<=image` to skip matching *image* in the indented comments.

Answer (score 5):

[This mailing list post](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-to-make-search-skip-comments-tp1173144p1173148.html) suggest using [folds](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_only_in_unfolded_text):

> To search only in open folds (unfolded text):
>
> ```
> :set fdo-=search
> ```

To fold `#` comments, adapting on [this Vi and Vim post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3513/205) (where an `autocmd` for Python files is given):

```
set foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\s*#'
```

However, folding by default works only on multiple lines. You need to [enable folding of a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19037549/2072269), for single-line comments to be excluded:

```
set fml=0
```

After folding everything ([`zM`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#zM), since I did not have anything else to be folded), a search for `/image` does not match anything in the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure if the behavior changed in the middle, but at least for now, `:set fdo-=search` only prevents the fold that contains matches from opening.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way to ignore matches inside end-of-line comment markers (which does not account for the more complicated case of avoiding literal string delimiters, which could be achieved for a simpl-ish case if you want) is:

```
/\v%(^.{-}\/\/.{-})@<!<%(this|that|self|other)>
```

Where:

- [`/`](https://web.archive.org/web/20070613145028/http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%3CCR%3E) is the *ex* command to execute the search (remove if using the regex as part of another command, or a vimscript expression).
- `\v` forces the ["*very magic*"](https://web.archive.org/web/20070613145028/http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cv) for this regex.
- `\/\/` is the end-of-line comment token (*escaped*, so the `/` characters are not interpreted as the end of the regex by vim).  The example above works for C/C++, JavaScript, Node.JS, etc.
- `(^.{-}\/\/.{-})@<!` is the [*zero-width*](https://web.archive.org/web/20070613145028/http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/zero-width) expression that means "there should not be any comments preceding the start of the expression following this" (see [vim's documentation for `\@<!`](https://web.archive.org/web/20070613145028/http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@%3C!)).  In our case, this expression is just trying to find the end-of-line comment token at any point in the line (hence the [`^.{-}`](https://web.archive.org/web/20070613145028/http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%7B-)) *and* making sure that the *zero-width* match can end up in the first character of the positive expression that follows this one (achieved by the `.{-}` at the end of the parenthesised expression).
- `<%(this|that|self|other)>` can be replaced by any regex.  In this case, this shows that you can match an arbitrary expression at this point, without worrying about the comments (which are handled by the *zero-width* expression preceding this one).

As an example, consider the following piece of code:

```
some.this = 'hello'
  some.this = 'hello' + this.someother;
 some.this = 'hello' + this.someother; // this is a comment, and this is another
```

The above expression will match all the `this` words, except the ones inside the comment (or any other `//`-prefixed comments, for that matter).

(Note: links all pointing to the [`vim-7.0` reference documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20070613145131/http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/help.html), which should (and does in my own testing) also work in the latest vim and nvim releases as of the time of writing)